# rqt_console and rqt_logger_level

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm am very new to ROS, I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and ROS Fuerte. I have been going through the tutorials and I came across a problem, when I type the command:

rosrun rqt_console rqt_console

I get:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rqt_console below /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rqt/rqt_console
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rqt/rqt_console
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rqt/rqt_console/src/rqt_console

and similarly with rqt_logger_level, although the rqt_gui/rqt_graph works fine. Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks and best regards,

Khalid Yousif

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50238/rqt_console-and-rqt_logger_level/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial works for ROS groovy, but not fuerte. I will create a bug report.

EDIT3:
It seems the rqt_gui command has been replaced by a global rqt command in groovy, so from now on these should work in Groovy:

```
$ rqt 
$ rqt -s rqt_console
$ rqt -s rqt_logger_level
```

in Fuerte, (and for some time during Groovy beta), you could do this instead:

```
$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui
```

and select Plugins > Console in the menu. That has the same effect.

EDIT:
Or, to get exactly the same, run

```
$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui -s rqt_console
$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui -s rqt_logger_level
```

EDIT2:
See
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/54

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2012-12-14**:
Thanks for your fast response